# Linux Command - find images smaller than x pixels in height

Tags: linux, command, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to find and print all images in a directory and subdirectories with width or height smaller than x pixels. Running this on Ubuntu System

The command below works well, but it returns images that have the width smaller than x, which is the first value in the output. What do I have to change to get it to evaluate the height which is the second value. Don't mind running this once for width and once for height.

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -exec file {} \; | sed 's/\(.*jpg\): .* \([0-9]*x[0-9]*\).*/\2 \1/' | awk 'int($1) < 200 {print}' >output.txt
```

The output looks like this and as you can see the width is < 200. What needs change to return images that have the height < 200 regardless of the width.

```
168x320 ./actif/actif-organic-multivitamin-for-women-age-60-with-3-B075RCHPZV.jpg
142x500 ./actiiv/actiiv-recover-thickening-hair-loss-conditioner-16-0.jpg
190x500 ./actiiv/actiiv-recover-thickening-cleansing-hair-loss-sham-B07X2W44PN.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split column with awk into further columns than filter specific height or width.

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -exec file {} \; | sed 's/\(.*jpg\): .* \([0-9]*x[0-9]*\).*/\2 \1/' | awk  -F '[x,"./"]' 'int($1) < 200 || int($2) < 200 {print}'
```

First $1 is Width and $2 is Height.

In this above command using [OR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/02/unix-awk-operators/) operator to fetch width or height lower than 200px.

Comment: Welcome. Consider editing so the link to includes the O in OR.